# Spring Batch compare two tables in itemReader

Tags: spring-batch

Is there anyway we can compare two different tables based on any specific column  using Spring Batch.

For example:

**Table 1 Content:**

cust_id, cust_name,flag

**Table 2 Content:**

cust_id, cust_name,flag

My requirement is like this,

whenever a record is available in Table 1, I will insert the same into Table 2,
when record is deleted in Table 1,I will mark the flag in Table 2 as 'N'

Comment: Spring Batch does not offer any out of the box solutions for this. You would need to write customer Processor/Decider and use multiple writers to accomplish this

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need spring batch here, creating a over-head of DB IO read/write. Create Trigger in DB such that when insert/delete is performed  a trigger is generated and you will perform suitable task